# Better understanding of Orchard's idea of 'Shape'

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

[Basics uses this phrase to define/describe Shapes](http://orchardproject.net/docs/Basic-Orchard-Concepts.ashx):

> ...object that contains all the information...

Implies the ability to filter according to user type / role.

Exactly where can i see this magic in action / which learning curve twist do i bark up?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this article: [Accesing and rendering shapes](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes.ashx)
It introduces the basic concepts behind shape rendering. You should also read about dynamic objects (appropriate MSDN links are inside this article)

I wrote an article about using shapes as helpers, which gives some insight on how does it all work: [Using shapes as HTML helpers in Orchard](http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/using-shapes-as-html-helpers-in-orchard).

[EDIT]: I also wrote an [article](http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/customizing-orchard-shapes) today about shape customization. Hope that'll give you more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Some tutorials to better understand clay object like shapes:

- Malleable C# dynamic objects Part 1 [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/16/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-1-why-we-need-it.aspx)
- Malleable C# dynamic objects Part 2 [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/18/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-2.aspx).